# How to get a font PostScript name?

Tags: pdf, winapi, fonts, pdf-generation

I'm adding the possibility to embed Truetype fonts in the PDFs generated by my application, but the fonts **"Sitka Text"** (and it's variants "Sitka Banner", "Sitka small" and etc) and **"Meiryo"** don't embed.

I believe it is because I'm using the name from the [LOGFONT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms931108.aspx) object and to these fonts I should be using the PostScript name.

**How can I obtain the Postscript name?**

I obtained the ['name' table](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6name.html) with [GetFontData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getfontdata) but the result didn't return any name I could use.

Is there any method on WINAPI that gives me that name?

**Edit:** I only show to my users fonts with the embedding permissions *"Editable"* and *"Installable"* which I obtain with the methods [EnumFontFamiliesEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-enumfontfamiliesexa) and it's [CALLBACK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/a4adad4c-ab6a-4adb-a1d3-fea3cfdbaf73) function.

I also checked the [NEWTEXTMETRIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-tagnewtextmetrica) ntmFlags that shows all my fonts are NTM_TT_OPENTYPE.

**Edit2:** By don't embed I mean that the PDF readers don't show my font as embedded (and Acrobat doesn't show any text)

An [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ohhgd1r6sywr4t/Teste_Sitka_001_SO.pdf?dl=0) of the error.

**SOLVED**
first, I'd like to thanks Michael Mckeough and mkl, You guys are Awesome and helped me a lot, I checked my original font and it wasn't damaged and I didn't change the font bytes, but then I finally noticed that if you call GetFontData to a (.ttc) file it will crop the ttcf part and no PDF reader will be able to understand what font it was.

Comment: *"the fonts ... don't embed."* - what does that mean? Does the application reject the fonts? In that case you should find out why, it's your application after all. Do viewers reject the PDF created by your application? In that case you should share an example PDF others can reproduce the issue with.

Comment: The font as embedded in your example PDF appears broken. Font Forge and Font Validator both choke on it. Are you sure your original font is undamaged? Or does your embedding code manipulate the font somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally, you would find this in the "name" table of the font. It would be nameId 0x0006, in a form useful for your platform. The format of the name table is a part of the TrueType and OpenType specifications. (You can find a copy here [Microsoft Typography OpenType spec Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/name)). There can be an awful lot of entries in the table, or there may be few. In particular, the Postscript name may or may not be present in any given font. You will need to look through the table for nameID of 0x0006, and a form (language, platform, encoding) that you can use. For postscript names, you most likely want them to be English, ASCII encoded, for any platform.

However, it is unlikely that the font is not embedding for this reason! A more common reason is that it is not legal to embed this font. In the [Microsoft Typography OpenType Spec OS/2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2%20%22Microsoft%20Typography%20OpenType%20Spec%20OS/2) you will see a field named fsType. This field contains flags indicating under what circumstances this font is licensed to be embedded. No Reputable tool will embed or subset this font is these flags indicate is it not licensed to be embedded.

I see that "Sitka Text" is a MS Windows 10 font, freely distributed by windows. It seems unlikely that It would not be licensed for embedding. Interestingly, the tool I usually use for "looking at" a font quickly (Font Validator, which used to be available from Microsoft Typography, but appears to no longer be) tells me that the OS/2 record is invalid. That it specifies a type of 5, and the spec says that type 4 is the latest. The correct response to a request to embed would require access to the fsType field, and if the record format was unknown, it should "fail safe", and refuse to embed the font.

So this is the most likely reason that the font will not embed for you.

Comment: And as a side note, Font Validator does say the names table is present, correct, and contains Postscript names. It does not tell me what they are though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm checking the font embedding permissions so I believe it's not that, I'm embedding my fonts following the PDF manual for TrueType fonts, do you know of any difference in between Sitka and for example "Comics Sans" that would make the embedding process different? for example, I believe both fonts are TrueType, are they?

Comment: Comic Sans is also a truetype font. It has a Type3 OS/2 record, and an fsType of Editable Embedding. The only real difference I see between the two is the type of the OS/2 table.

Comment: My own toolset embeds Sitka with no issues. It is not checking the type of OS/2 record at all. It shows the postscript name as "SitkaText".

Comment: *"Font Validator, which used to be available from Microsoft Typography, but appears to no longer be"* - it appears to have gone [to github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Font-Validator), a more actively maintained fork is [here](https://github.com/HinTak/Font-Validator).